# Hide red bar while recording in background

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

My app keeps listening to voices and analysis them to detect real panic screams. So I want to keep the app running 24/7, but when my app goes in background, the red bar appears on top. Since the recording has to be running for longer period, my app users won't afford to use it anymore. Do you think there is anyway to hide it while recording in background, does Apple has such policy to allow us in such case?
The same question was asked but none is given an answer yet.

I am using `AVAudioSession` with category `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` with options `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`

Comment: I see no point people down voting this question. If you are down voting it, please write some reason of doing so too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you think there is anyway to hide it while recording in background

Not "while recording in background". The user needs to know that this is happening.

You *can* eliminate the red bar — by changing your category and *not* recording in the background.

But you cannot record in the background *without* showing the red bar while you are in the background.